# Simplest upgrade data from ElasticSearch 2 to ElasticSearch 6?

Tags: elasticsearch

We're looking to migrate our clusters with ElasticSearch 2.x to the latest version. What is the simplest way to do this?

I already wrote a deploy script for deploying the ELK 2 stack and the ELK 6 stack. Unfortunately ElasticSearch 6.x cannot read data from ElasticSearch 2.x.

**Go via ElasticSearch 5**

Is it worth to make also a deploy script for an ELK-5, so it will automatically upgrade all my data without data loss? It's mostly logs.

Then we'd have to do 2 deploys on all environments and ElasticSearch would convert all data for us from the old to the newer version.

**ElasticSearch 2 and 6 next to each other**

Can we not better change the fluentd configuration to write log files to both ELK-2 and ELK-6 for a week at the same time. Then we delete the ELK-2 cluster a week later? That way we don't have to do weird stuff with building a new ElasticSearch-5 script and going through 2 deploys and 2 data upgrades.

Comment: Do you need to keep your old ES2 indexes in the new ES6 cluster? If not, then you should spin up a new ES6 cluster and write your data both on ES2 and ES6 until you have enough data in ES6. Then decommission the ES2 cluster.

Comment: Yeah, that does seem a good solution to me. I'll have to verify we don't need any data.

Comment: If you only need one week of data there's no point in reindexing the ES2 data to ES6. A parallel run would be the most logical solution to me